# when transfering the lite db from rails to PG do you need to rewrite the db code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

I am planning to deploy my website later and need to know the lite DB in the development/testing stage of the app that needs to be changed to PG especially when the websites allows its users to do a number of tasks which require a number of DBS.

When transferring the DB through deployment to a server; i.e. digital ocean, do you need to rewrite the DB code in the PG?

Comment: What do you mean here by the db code ???

Comment: DB Database PG Postgres. I need to know; Is it automatic, when your switch the sqlite3 databases from your development rails app to production postgres databases, Do you need to code the databases again or is it changed to postgres straight away without any need of touching the files. The website will continue to work.

Comment: Definitely, The schema and migrations are independent you can anytime switch to the database. But you will not be able to transport the data from one DB to another.

Comment: Thanks. So the databases on the postgres will store the new data for upcoming users.

Comment: As long as your Rails App was  using Active Record it will handle swapping databases for you and running all necessary migrations (sqlite/mysql/psql etc.).